# Computing integrals for divergent loop amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, integration

I am trying to compute the cross-section for the diagram below with a divergent triangle loop:
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

where $X^0$ and $X^-$ are some fermions with zero and negative charge respectively.  I am interested in low energy limits, so you can consider W-propagator as $\frac{i\eta_{\mu\nu}}{M_w^2}$.

When computing the amplitude, ignoring the external wave functions, you end of with an integration of the form:
$$ \int \frac {k_\mu \gamma^\mu +m_-} {k^2 -m_-^2 +i\epsilon} \frac {d^4 k} {(2\pi)^4} $$
where $m_-$ is mass of $X^-$.

Any ideas how to solve this integral in terms of kinematic parameters, masses etc?

Comment: Well, you notice yourself that the expression diverges. And I am not sure I understand how you get rid of the dependence of the W propagators on the loop momentum. The integrals are standard, look up Passarino-Veltman functions.

Comment: @marmot, for simplicity, I just assumed that the loop momentum is less than W boson mass. Maybe, I oversimplified the integral as that is an internal momentum.

Comment: You cannot make this assumption since the loop momentum gets integrated all the way up to infinity, as your formula shows.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with marnot that you can't get rid of W propagators in the loop.

That being said, the integral *per se* 
$$
\int \frac {k_\mu \gamma^\mu +m_-} {k^2 -m_-^2 +i\epsilon} \frac {d^4 k} {(2\pi)^4}
$$
is a typical single fermion loop (e.g. a vacuum bubble diagram), where the first term related to
$$
k_\mu \gamma^\mu 
$$
drops out since it's odd in $k_\mu$.

The second term related to
$$
m_-
$$
is quadratic divergent, which amounts to zero however in dimensional regularization (one of the peculiarities of DR).

Comment: Why do you say the second term is zero?

Comment: It's one of the quirks of DR.

Comment: It’s well understood and only vanishing for certain $d$ and if there’s no scale. Here there is a scale $m$_ present so you’re not dealing with a scaleless integral.